# Use 'Connect-AzAccount' command of PowerShell in C#

Tags: .net, azure, powershell, azure-connect

I want to connect to Azure the same way I log in using Powershell commands. Since I have not found any API to do that with  .NET, I thought that a good idea would be to execute PS scripts with.NET.

I have already installed the Powershell for azure on my laptop

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber
```

I also tried to use the 'Connect-AzAccount' command just with the Windows Powershell of my PC and it works fine.

So, I tried the following in Visual Studio:

```
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace AzureTestVM
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Connect-AzAccount");
            ps.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get the following error :

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Method
'get_SerializationSettings' on type' 
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient 'of assembly' 
Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Clients.ResourceManager, Version = 1.0. 0.0, Culture = neutral,    
PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35 'does not have an implementation. --->
 System.TypeLoadException: Method 'get_SerializationSettings' on type' 
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient 'of assembly' 
Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Clients.ResourceManager, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, 
PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35 'does not have an implementation.
```

Comment: this link may help you- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/475747/use-39connect-azaccount39-command-of-powershell-in.html